# How to redicrect DNS requests to DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dns, routing

My computer's internal IP is `10.100.0.1`. My computer has specified DNS server `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf`. I want to allow other computers use my computer's default DNS server (specified in network configuration or `/etc/resolv.conf` file) specifying my computer's internal IP (`10.100.0.1`) as DNS server. My computer somehow must redirect all DNS requests to a DNS server which is configured as default (currently `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf`). How can I do it?
Hope for your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to install a DNS forwarder on your computer, or do you want other computers to use 8.8.8.8, or do you want to copy /etc/resolv.conf from your computer to other computers? In the first case, I suggest `dnsmasq`. In the second case, just enter 8.8.8.8 in the other computers' `/etc/resolv.conf`. In the third case, use `rsync` or another remote copy command to copy `/etc/resolv.conf`. If it's none of the above, please clarify.

Comment: @berndbausch, first case, thanks

Comment: dnsmasq is your solution then.